# How to adjust width of Bulma Table Column

Tags: html, css, html-table, bulma

I am trying to create a calendar using Bulma table, everything is working properly except one problem.
My calendar looks like below

[image]

You can see that the column widths are not uniform (for example, **Fri** column width is smaller than **Mon** column width) and it should not be like this, everyday of the calendar should have same width. Below is the code snippet for this

```
<table class="table is-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I am not sure about how to solve this, using CSS or any other better way. I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give all tds an equal width.

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  text-align:center;
  width:14.2%;
  padding:5px;
}
th
{
   background:#DDEEEE;
}
table {
  width: 400px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="table is-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```